# Py2app packaged pyqt4 programs can't run on other mac

Tags: macos, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I've written a python script and work well on my mac,but when I using py2app and run app with other mac.it's wrong.

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dfrobot/Downloads/1.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 137, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/dfrobot/Downloads/1.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 121, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/dfrobot/Downloads/1.app/Contents/Resources/1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
  File "PyQt4/QtCore.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "PyQt4/QtCore.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "imp.pyc", line 343, in load_dynamic
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dfrobot/Downloads/1.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/PyQt4/QtCore.so 

, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
  Referenced from: /Users/dfrobot/Downloads/1.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/PyQt4/QtCore.so
```

Unexpectedly, when I installed QT on other mac, it work well. Why?